# Troubleshooting DNS access issue on local network

Tags: configuration, dns, error-handling

I have installed a DNS by creating the two zones on my server, CentOS 7. Here are the steps:

1. `vi /etc/hosts`

   ```
   etienne  credo.local etienne
   ```
2. `yum install bind bind-utils`
3. `vi /etc/named.config`

   ```
   zone"credo.local"{
       type master
      file "/var/named/directe"
     }   
   zone"credo.local"{
      file "/var/named/indirecte"
     }  
   listen port{192.168.5.1}
   allow request {192.168.5.0/24}
   ```
4. `cp /var/named/named. Localhost   /var/named/direct`
5. `cp /var/named/named. Localhost   /var/named/indirect`

NB: My DNS is working very well, but only on my computer with this ip 192.168.5.1, but others in the same network don't. What could be the main cause of that error?

Comment: The configuration file for BIND is `/etc/named.conf`, not `/etc/named.config`. And the syntax of your configuration file looks wrong in other ways too: there are space and semicolon characters missing where they absolutely should be present. Did you just put your entire question through machine translation, and it ruined the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`.local` is reserved for multicast DNS, so you'll want to pick a different zone name.

That bind configuration file doesn't look valid. The reason you're seeing it work on the local host but not elsewhere is because local clients are resolving using the `/etc/hosts` file.
You need to configure bind properly with a zone file for other clients to work correctly.

See https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter3.html for a basic overview of isc-bind9 configuration.